# Possible Promise Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, promise, bluebird

Hi this works for the first execution but then when I try again it seems to break, does anything seem wrong with the way the promises are used here

```
    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback) {
    return getUsersFromDb()
    .then(function() {
        if (users.name.indexOf(data) > -1) {
            callback(false);
            reject(err);
        } 
        else {
            callback(true);
            // socket.nickname = data;
            // people[socket.nickname] = socket;
            updateNicknames();
            var user = new User();
            user.name = data;
            user.save(function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)    
                }
                else {
                    return getUsersFromDb()
                    .then(function() {
                        updateNicknames()
                    })
                    .catch(function(e) {
                        console.log("Error", e)
                    })
                }
            });
            socket.broadcast.emit('user join', {nick: socket.nickname});
        } 
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
        console.log("Error", e)
    })
});
```

Sublime seems to colour the then and catch inside the second else differently as if it was used wrongly

Comment: What is the `socket` variable?  Is it a socket.io connection?  Or a plain socket connection?  Also, why are you calling `reject(err)`.  Where is `reject()` defined?  And, why do you think that the second argument to the `socket.on()` callback is a callback itself?  What does `updateNicknames()` do?  What debugging have you done when it doesn't work?  Do you know what code path it takes?  What errors do you get?  This sounds like you need to do elemental debugging first so you can tell us exactly where the code goes wrong.

Comment: your code really need restruct, what do u return for? u should pass in a promise to then if u have multiple async calls, and chain them up

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the following function returns a promise!?

```
getUsersFromDb()
```

Have you tried jQuery promise, using $.when(functionWhichReturnsAPromise()).then( "the rest of the code")?

Comment: First off, this is server-side code (thus jQuery is not really appropriate).  Second off, there is no reason to use `$.when()` with a single promise.  You can just call `.then()` directly on the promise you already have.  This does not really seem to provide any sort of answer to the OP's question.